# Save attach of attached mail

Tags: c#, imap

I'm using Mail.dll from limilabs to manage an IMAP folder.
There is one mail with an attachment that is an eml file, so a mail.
It has in turn one attached eml file that I need to extract.

So the email structure is as follows:

```
Email
  |- Attachment: file.eml
                   |- Attachment file2.eml
```

This is my code:

```
IMail email = new MailBuilder().CreateFromEml(imap.GetMessageByUID(uid));
Console.WriteLine(email.Subject);
// save all attachments to disk
foreach(MimeData mime in email.Attachments)
{
if (uid == 1376)
{
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(string.Format(@"c:\EMAIL\{0}", uid));
        mime.Save(@"c:\EMAIL\" + uid + "\\" + mime.SafeFileName);
        MimeData help;
        if (mime.ContentType.ToString() == "message/rfc822")
        {
        //i need to cast this attach in a imail
        }
    }
}
```

How can I extract the inner-most eml file (file2.eml in the structure mentioned above)?

Comment: Is there a question in there?  What issue are you having?

Comment: Excuse me if I was not clear. The problem is that the first attached mail is seen like an attach, not like a mail, so it hasn't the imail property, but it has an attach file that i need to download separately.

Comment: Seeing as this is a fairly specific component, and it is also a paid component, I think you'll have more chance getting an answer by using their support form (http://www.limilabs.com/support).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this link](http://www.limilabs.com/blog/process-emails-embedded-as-attachments), it looks like you should be able to do the following:

```
if (attachment.ContentType == ContentType.MessageRfc822)
{
    string eml = ((MimeText)attachment).Text;
    IMail attachedMessage = new MailBuilder().CreateFromEml(eml);
    // process further
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to extract all attachments from all inner messages, you can use *IMail.ExtractAttachmentsFromInnerMessages* method:

```
IMail email = new MailBuilder().CreateFromEml(imap.GetMessageByUID(uid));

ReadOnlyCollection<MimeData> attachments = mail.ExtractAttachmentsFromInnerMessages();
foreach (MimeData mime in attachments)
{
     mime.Save(@"c:\" + mime.SafeFileName);
}
```